# PHP Code not searching if 2 variables used for the parameteres

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                $restext = $row['pagetext'];            
                echo "<br /><br />$restext <br /><br />";


                $user = str_replace('[TD="align: left"]'.$uid.'[/TD]','<b>LOOLOLOOLOLOLO</b>', $restext); 

                if (strpos($user,'<b>LOOLOLOOLOLOLO</b>')===false) {

                    $test = '[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';

                    if (strpos($test, $restext)!==false) {

                        echo "Base not reserved!";

                    }
                    else
                        echo "This base is already reserved!";


                }
                else
                    echo "You have already reserved a base!";                   
            }
```

The problem is with the last part where I use this:

```
if (strpos($test, $restext)!==false) {

    echo "Base not reserved!";

}
else
    echo "This base is already reserved!";
```

It just doesn't work.

That code always outputs: `This base is already reserved!`

Even if I know it should be outputting `Base not reserved!`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The debugging I have done:

I am able to `echo $rextext` and `$test`

If I change the  if statement to: `if (strpos($test, "blah blah the text goes here")!==false) {`

It will work but I can't keep it like that because the text is dynamically pulled from the dB.

Thanks!

Comment: what is $num? it's not define?

Comment: It's defined, it's a number.

Comment: Echo out both vars at the start of the function to see if they equal

Comment: @Matt Holbrook-Bull They equal What They should.